Can I set up an automatic definitions repository?
So, I have a question I really struggle to put into coherent words, but I'll try my best.
I've worked in LaTeX quite a bit, but I recently wanted to start fully switching over to TeX notes during lectures instead of writing. When preparing for an exam recently, I had compiled a document of every definition, theorem, proposition, and basically every amsthm environment I had defined into one file.
It got me thinking, is there a good way to automatically do something like that? I met with a professor and his suggestion was to write a bash script to parse files and print them which seems fairly straightforward, but he also said I could try my hand at writing a package.
Before I bite off so much though, is there something that is readily available in this vein? Is there an approach I haven't mentioned that would be recommended?

welcome! not sure exactly what you're looking for - something on the parsing-files side or something on the pretty-printing side? the former would be better done not by tex, imho. sed/gawk or I'm sure perl/python etc. have things. that's not to say you couldn't do it in tex (at least with lua), but I don't see why you would. if, on the other hand, you set up a set of files to hold the definitions database-like, then that's a different matter. e.g. glossaries.

Welcome. // Perhaps this package helps you? https://ctan.org/pkg/extract // It would be good if you‘d prepare a demo document with all or the most relevant structures you want to extract, and add it to your question. Thank you

You probably better to do both. say your daily notes are 1.tex,2.tex,3.tex..... You need a CLI script to wrap these  either individually or in a range.  Your own command definitions are better in a .sty file, easier to maintain, or a .cls, so from the command line you can say \mycompiler 1.tex  If you dont want to write the CLI script, then a more intelligent main.tex  can do this (IMHO easier, provided you have a consistent naming convention for your daily files. I suggest you name your daily files as 2024-08-29.tex etc.... Pls explain your daily routine...

Here is a way to do it with package extract.
Your main file(s)
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    active,
    generate=file,              % writes to file.tex
    copydocumentclass=false,
    extract-env={figure,Def},   % add environments here
    ]{extract}
    
\usepackage{lipsum}             % to simulate some content

\input{preamb}                  % things needed in file.tex

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
\begin{extract} % if you need a different documentclass
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
    \input{preamb}              % things needed in file.tex
\end{extract}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
\begin{document}
 Some text.
 
 \lipsum[5] 
 
 \begin{Def}
    Here is a nice little definition.
 \end{Def}
 
 What does it lead to?
 
 
 \begin{Def}
    An other nice little definition.
 \end{Def}
 
 \begin{figure}
  \centering tbd
  \caption{Some figure}
 \end{figure} 
 
\end{document}

I'd put (and \input) macros, packages etc. which you also need to compile the extracted file e.g. in file preamb.tex, because else you'd have to enter them in two places:
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}


Extracted file
It will be file.tex, as specified:
\usepackage[
    active,
    generate=file,              % writes to file.tex
...

which contains
%% 
%% This is file, `file.tex',
%% generated with the extract package.
%% 
%% Generated on :  2024/09/29,19:06
%% From source  :  xtrex1.tex
%% Using options:  active,generate=file,copydocumentclass=false,extract-env={figure,Def},
%% 
% if you need a different documentclass
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\input{preamb} % things needed in file.tex

\begin{document}

\begin{Def}
  Here is a nice little definition.
 
\end{Def}

\begin{Def}
  An other nice little definition.
 
\end{Def}

\begin{figure}
  \centering tbd
  \caption{Some figure}
 
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Numbering may be an issue, as this document will be compiled as usual.
